# Facebook Native Ads Manager Error

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

I'm using facebook audience network `NativeAdsManager` from v4.1.0 to load a batch of ads. It did work in one device, but failed in another. When calling `loadAds()`, it yields `AdError` saying `No Fill`. Does anyone know what it means? I've searched for documentations but found nothing in that particular matter.

Below is my init code.

```
NativeAdsManager adsManager = new NativeAdsManager(this, "PLACEMENT_ID", 10);
adsManager.setListener(this);
adsManager.loadAds();
```

Answer (score 3):

Audience network uses people-based targeting so server ads. It may not be able to fill requests from all devices. To ensure you always get ads on a certain device, check the logcat output for a line that looks like:

```
AdSettings.addTestDevice("HASHED ID");
```

Follow the instruction there and add that device as a test device, then you will always get ads for requests from that device.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I just re-read facebook docs on audience network, and it does seem that sometimes there is just nothing to show. It's my bad for not reading carefully. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: Does it specify exactly how to generate the HASHED_ID for a device?

Comment: AdSettings.addTestDevice("HASHED ID");. Use the hashed ID that is printed to the log cat when you first make a request to load an ad on a device."

Which means look for "AdSettings" in the logcat. Can't say that's particularly well documented by Facebook

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by reducing the number of ads which should be loaded. For example, 5 ads work for me.

```
NativeAdsManager adsManager = new NativeAdsManager(this, "PLACEMENT_ID", 5);
```